# Would this chambered cylinder be possible?

Tags: atmospheric-science, space, buoyancy, lift

Could a flexible light weight chambered cylinder (looks similar to bamboo) was filled with helium and stood up to reach outside the atmosphere? 
Each chamber would have a different psi according to its altitude and external atmospheric psi. Hot helium could be used to lift each chamber at time and as it cools it would equalize with the atmosphere.
Would it be able to stay upright on its own weight/buoyancy? Why not? At the very least it could serve as the bottom half of a space elevator?

[image]

Comment: Seems more like an engineering question to me.

Comment: @user1583209 I will ask there as well. Thanks but i need to know if it is physically possible?

Comment: In principle you could build a regular tower (without that helium magic) to reach the atmosphere. It is just a question of whether your materials can handle the load (and available resources). I don't see any problems with physics other than engineering challenges.

Comment: Of course, the atmosphere doesn't end abruptly as suggested by your diagram, but fades out gradually. Also, the buoyant force associated with a helium balloon of a given size will tend to decrease as the ambient pressure decreases because there will be less of a weight difference between a given mass of air and that of helium of the same volume. Perhaps that's why you drew the 'cylinder' as more of a conical shape.

Comment: @SamuelWeir that is drawn in that way for  that reason. thanks

Comment: I tried to balance the votes, I like your post. I would bet that to build any structure is complicated, so please don't put yourself down that way (or your least educated comment either, I feel the same with a lot of the scary questions here).  It  is more engineering than physics, but I would think you could ask it in a physics way.  But even if we built it, how useful would it be, it would hard to put any weight on the side of it.

Comment: @CountTo10 It could be used as a landing platform at the top or at the least the bottom half of the space elevator.

Comment: Well, Jen, if people are willing to pay $250,000 to fly to space for 15 minutes with Virgin Galactic,  (and risk their lives ), which lots of people are, [Virgin Galactic](http://www.virgingalactic.com/human-spaceflight/fly-with-us/),  you could charge far less, they would be much safer, and could stay up there a lot  longer.  And parachute down, as some people would do that, but not me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not think it would be able to stay upright on its own. The main difficulty which I anticipate is the wind, especially the strong winds encountered in the upper atmosphere. These will push sideways all along the length of the balloon, bending it over on its side until it is almost horizontal.

In order to reach up to a certain height, it will have to be much, much longer than the straight-up distance. I would guess of the order of 100 km to reach a height of 10 km. This will add considerably to the amount of material required, and to the lateral forces on it. Although the buoyancy of the helium could provide an upward force to counteract the weight of the structure, it can do nothing to relieve the sideways force of the wind.

The material used would have to be extremely strong to prevent the wind from tearing it apart. The tension in the structure would increase all the way down to the base, which would have to withstand the sum of all sideways forces from the wind along the length of the balloon.

It would be a monumental task to build it, dwarfing every other civil engineering project in history in size and cost, and a nightmare to keep it under control in unpredictable winds. The cost of rides would be more than in a high-altitude jet.

What use would it be? As a launch-pad for rockets or as a "sky-station" it would have to carry considerable extra weight, adding to the size of the buoyancy chambers, and to the dangers if it was torn apart. It would provide no saving in the cost of getting into space, because fuel would be required to get up to it.

Some calculations could be done to entertain you with the numbers, but I don't think there is any point in doing so.

Comment: I disagree I am sure there is a place where climate could be calm most of the year.  It would be attached to the ground would not lean much for its size.  In the event of a major storm the helium could be collected and stored and the elevator laid down.  The only reason wind is known to be stronger at higher elevation would be the jet steam and the focus of air on top of a mountain.  Air is also thinner and have less pushing force the higher it is. In order to hold the weight it would have to be big but still would use far less material compared to existing concepts for a space elevator.

Comment: What do you think of the laser induced energy transfer?

Comment: @Muze : Why aren't you posting on Science Fiction & Fantasy, Jen? Or Space Exploration?